# Ifnull using FMDB

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I've just switched my iOS app from using plain SQLite to using FMBD. It's going great and I am a big fan. The only problem I'm having is that I have used the `ifnull` function in a number of my old SQLite calls, and it doesn't seem to work with FMDB. I get a message saying

> Warning: I could not find the column named 'columnName'

I've tried a number of different ways of calling the statement, but I could be missing something simple.

Is there any way around this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `IFNULL` appears to work fine with FMDB. You might want to show us a simplified code that manifests the problem. Generally you get that error if you use one of the `FMResultSet` methods with an invalid column name, but to generate the error you reported, you would have had to literally have something like `[rs stringForColumn:@"columnName"]` or `rs[@"columnName"]` (where you had `@"columnName"` rather than the actual column name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use IFNULL with FMDB and it works perfect

Trivial, but have you tried:

```
IFNULL(columnName, "I am sad, because I am NULL") as columnName
```

Comment: Yes. This is correct, I worked it out a while back, but forgot to update this question